# GCE - What is startpar: service(s) returned failure: google-address-manager google google-startup-scripts ... FAIL ... failed

Tags: startup, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a GCE v1 instance for the first time.  I had used beta up to this point.

After setting up my first Debian Wheezy server, with default network settings (default-allow-internal, default-ssh, external-web, test8443), I booted it up and tried to SSH into it.

$ gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="project name" ssh  --zone="us-central1-a" "hostname"

error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

$ gcutil version
1.13.0

Looking at the instance console, I see google-startup-scripts errors.

Dec 22 07:48:38 saas-prototype-v1 ntpd[1981]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
[....] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd[?25l[?1c7[1G[[32m ok [39;49m8[?25h[?0c.

Dec 22 07:48:38 saas-prototype-v1 startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script

Dec 22 07:48:38 saas-prototype-v1 startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
[....] startpar: service(s) returned failure: google-address-manager google google-startup-scripts ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?25h[?0c [31mfailed![39;49m

INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel

Dec 22 07:48:38 saas-prototype-v1 init: no more processes left in this runlevel

What's causing this?  None of the v1 instances I create are usable.  To connect to a beta instance, I have to point specifically to the beta gcutil executable to connect to a beta instance.  I'm in an awkward state.

Comment: Doublechecking: Have you updated the kernels for your Persistent Disks and Images? https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1#customkernelbinaries

Comment: I created a new empty project with the same results. 
$ ./gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:
…
Enter you Google Cloud project id (or leave blank to not set): project name
You are logged in as user@domain.com.
$ gcutil getproject
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
$ gcutil version
1.13.0

Comment: Rephrasing: I created new compute instances using the supported kernels in that project but was unable to ssh in using either gcutil 1.8.4 or 1.13.0.  I then created a new empty project and gcutil 1.13.0 refuses to connect to the new project even after running 'gcloud auth login'.

Comment: Do you have another computer available that you could try gcutil from, to help determine if the error is specific to that machine environment or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also problems with startup script.

Jan  3 17:21:45 withstartupscript startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
Jan  3 17:21:45 withstartupscript startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
[....] startpar: service(s) returned failure: google-address-manager google google-startup-scripts ...[?25l[?1c7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?25h[?0c [31mfailed![39;49m

....

Ok after a lots of rebooting of an instance linux, very fast rebooting, the problem is that the startup-script should be a text file! Not an bash-script, but a text file.

Google Developers Console has the Custom Metadata field, under the instance name. Add there a "startup-script" key and put there any code to test, and you can reboot the instance and check that it works.